# Kubernetes gives NodeHasInsufficientMemory even though nodes has enough memory

Tags: kubernetes, memory-management, out-of-memory, kubernetes-pod

[image]

There 3 worker nodes in the cluster and each node has 64GB of memory. As you can see in the picture, memory usage is only 29%. But it is giving the NodeHasInsufficientMemory.
Any idea why?

Comment: Please provide more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What kind of cluster do you use? Kubeadm or managed by cloud GKE, EKS, AKS? Which version of kubernetes do you use? What application do you use on these nodes and how many pods? Please provide logs of them